# Missing print() output to vs-code terminal

Tags: python, terminal, visual-studio-code

I'm relatively new to Python programming and have been using vs code. Up until very recently, while running a script, `print()` statement would appear in the vs code integrated terminal. But now they don't, and I can't figure out what happened. I've re-install vs code but no change, I've looked through the setting but can find anything. 
If anyone can help, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Hi, wecome to SO. Can you paste the code for us to see? That will help us help you

Comment: Did you check if your current being used terminal is the current displaying terminal?

Comment: Is the print statement in ```if``` loop?